# Facebook "Like" popup appears behind sidebar on Wordpress site

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

Just finished installing G+, Facebook Like and Tweet buttons onto my site (www.biginjapan.co) on each individual post.  My issue though is that when you press the FB Like button the popup box opens up so you can share the article if desired, but part of it appears behind the sidebar.  It looks like this:

[Picture showing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2DI5.jpg)

Am not sure if you'll need any code to advise me here, but if you do please let me know.  All I want to do is make the Facebook popup appear above the sidebar so you can view it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `overflow: hidden` for #content. it's on line 247.

Answer (score 0):

In your content div

```
#content {
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   width: 619px;
   padding: 0pt 15px;
}
```

Remove overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It is layer issue. It can be handle by z-index. For the slider layer (content), use lower z-index means

```
.slider{ z-index: -1; }
```

For the popup layer (content ) use higher z-index than slider

```
.popup{ z-index: 123; }
```